# Byte Stuffing, escaping a flag at maximum frame

Tags: computer-networks, encoding-scheme

I want to encode a message using byte stuffing where every frame delimited by a flag byte 'F' at both ends and escape code equal to the character E. I am trying to encode the message 'DEEP-FRIED-FALAFELS' while the maximum window size is 10bytes.

What I am unsure about is, what happens when I try to escape a 'flag' or 'esc' but the maximum frame is reached. Do I continue onto the next frame as I have shown below or are am I meant to esc at the beginning of the next frame.

This is my supposed answer
Frame1: **F**D**E**E**E**EP-**EF**,
Frame2: **F**FRI**E**ED-**E**F,
Frame3: **F**FALA**E**F**E**E**F**,
Frame4: **F**LS**F**